# Opencv CvSeq * add integer value to all points in sequence

Tags: c++, opencv

After usuing `cvFindContours( g_gray, g_storage, &contours )`  I need to add to all points in  sequence `CvSeq * contours` the integer value. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean adding a constant offset point to each point of the obtained contour. Check out the full function prototype at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cvFindContours:

`int cvFindContours(CvArr* image, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** first_contour, int header_size=sizeof(CvContour), int mode=CV_RETR_LIST, int method=CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CvPoint offset=cvPoint(0, 0))`

Just pass it a requisite value of offset, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!! that is i was finding for!